# Create a executable .jar with all automated tests

Tags: java, junit, automated-tests, cucumber

My test framework runs all `src/test/java` tests through the TestRunner class and works great when running on Eclipse.

However, I need to provide this automation for the end user to run on their machine, without the need for the Eclipse IDE installed.

I've tried in several ways through maven, but without success, I need a Help.

**Class TestRunner.java**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = { "src/test/resources/features" }, plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report",
        "json:target/cucumber-json-report/cucumber.json" },
        monochrome = true, glue = { "" })

public class TestRunner {
}
```

**Maven commands I tried to generate the .jar**

```
mvn clean instal package
mvn test-compile
mvn test
mvn build
```

> The main class could not be found or loaded

[image: Framework]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, creating the jar file of the automation test script is not a best practice because I remember that I did the same thing. In windows, it was working perfectly but in ubuntu it was failing due to the missing of some dependencies. If you really want to run the project without IDE then I believe that you should ask that person to download the apache maven binaries from here https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi and then you just navigate to the root project folder where your pom.xml is present and run the maven command and make sure that you add the apache maven binaries path in the environment variables. If you want to execute it with the java code then you can use maven invoker dependency as well and if you are really willing to make it executable then you need to create this project in the spring boot and that could help you to fulfill your requirement.

```
InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
  request.setPomFile(session.getRequest().getPom());
  request.setGoals(goals);
  request.setAlsoMake(true);
  request.setUpdateSnapshots(updateSnapshots);
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.putAll(properties);
  request.setProperties(props);
  Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();
  boolean success;
  try {
    InvocationResult result = invoker.execute(request);
    success = result.getExitCode() == 0 && result.getExecutionException() == null;
  } catch (MavenInvocationException e) {
    throw new MojoExecutionException("Invocation error! " + ABORT, e);
  }
  failIf(!success, "An error occurred. " + ABORT);
```

---

I have created a sample project. You can download it from below.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ftIO06_92mZY7WkjcAiFTJJip5KURv4l

---

**Steps to create and execute runnable file:**

```
Step 1: Execute the MainClass.java file to create class file of it.
Step 2: In eclipse, Please export the project as Runnable jar
Step 3: Run the runnable jar with the following command
        Command: java -jar <name of the jar file>.jar classpath:<path of the features directory in jar file> --glue <path of the stepdefinitions directory in jar>
```

---

Tip: you can use 7zip to open the jar file and you can check the path of feature directory and step definition

Note: This is not a good practice. So I will recommend to use the maven project directly instead of jar file :) .

Comment: Excellent considerations, I'll think about it, but at the moment I really need to generate .jar to deliver automation to a lay user. Not sure where to create this src / test or src / main project?

Comment: No problem my friend. I will create a sample project for you :) Is it okay if I create the cucumber project with cucumber testng runner?

Comment: I have already updated my comment with the project  URL please check it out and let me know if you face any issue :)